# How to break apart multi digit number into separate number without swapping its order

Tags: c

I want to separate 4567 into  4,    5,    6,   7 , 
One of the way to separate was :

```
int value =4567, rightDigit;
rightDigit =number%10;
number /=10;
```

However the result was 7, 6, 5, 4, 
How do I get it to print 4 5 6 7 instead ? Thanks

Comment: Store in array, reverse array?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Or store in array and print in the opposite order.

Comment: Your first digit can be stored in a[3] rather than a[0], etc.

Comment: thanks for the tips, ill look into array now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to store the digits explicitly. You can use *the* [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to store them and print them in correct order.

```
void print_digits(int n) {
    // In case n is negative, print the leading '-'
    // and transform n to a non-negative number
    if(n < 0) {
        printf("-");
        n = -n;
    }
    if(n/10) {
        print_digits(n/10);
    }
    printf("%d", n%10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays or a stack would work just fine. You could also use a divisor (pseudocode):

```
num = whatever
div=1'000'000'000 // ints are 2 billion max
first = false
while div > 0:
  digit = num / div
  first = first or (digit != 0)
  if first: handleDigit(digit)
  num = num % div
  div = div / 10
```

It's less efficient and uncommon but should work.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to store all the digits,generated by the % 10 operation to an array and then print the array in reverse order.The code is as fllows-

```
int main()
{
    int i,c=0,value=4567,r,arr[10];
    while(value){
        r=value%10;
        arr[c++]=r;
        value/=10;
    }
    for(i=c-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using stack you can solve this problem.

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <stack>
    int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        queue<int> digit;
        int number;
        cin >> number;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            digit.push(number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }
        while (!digit.empty())
        {
            cout << digit.top() << " ";
            digit.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you don't need separate memory, call stack would do.